# Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped. (2015)

Tags: parsing, url, input, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

i share websites content through Facebook Open Graph on Facebook.
But some of the URL give the above error (though the url of posts and its images are correct).
in example.
this url works:
http://dehmazang.org/post?id=00061&cat=articles
or if i change its category(articles) to (roznigar)
it also works:
and if i just change its category(articles) to (goftago)
it doesn't work
and also changing to some other categories doesn't work.

I don't really know is there fault with website or Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is a place for people writing their own code, webapps might be a better place to ask, or superuser.stackexchange.com

Facebook's scraper works the same way with all website,  it's about the setup on their individual website, put the links into http://developers.facebook. com/tools/debug